# Generating 3 billion-th element of a sequence in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I am trying to generate the following sequence:

```
011212201220200112 ... constructed as follows: first is 0, 
then repeated the following action: 
already written part is attributed to the right with replacement 
0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 0.
E.g.

0 -> 01 -> 0112 -> 01121220 -> ...
```

I am trying to find the 3 billion-th element of this sequence.
I realized that the sequence grows exponentially and hence derived that:

```
log(base2) (3 billion)  ~ 32
```

So I just need to generate this sequence 32 times.

Here is what I tried in python:

```
import os
import sys



s=['0']
num_dict = {'0':'1' , '1':'2' , '2':'0'}

def mapper(b):  
    return num_dict[b]  


def gen(s):
    while True:         
        yield s     
        s.extend( map(mapper,s) )


a = gen(s)
for i in xrange(32):
    a.next()

print a.next()[3000000000 - 1]
```

The problem is my RAM gets filled up before hitting the 3 billion mark.
Is there a better way to do this problem ?

EDIT: This program could crash your machine.Please try for xrange(25) for testing purposes

Comment: This is Code Eval challenge 125: https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/125

Comment: Yes it is :) .... I am trying to find the sequence value for n == 3 billion

Comment: Use a [Generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Comment: There is a *really simple pattern* in that number sequence when you look at it as binary.

Comment: Oh wait, it looks like you already are, but you're doing so in a way that's expanding out the list, which is not what you want to do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Now that I look at it, yep, there sure is! Don't even need to use a generator if you don't want.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: look at it as a binary ??

Comment: @tomkaith13: the binary representation of N has a direct correlation to the digit found at position N. So the digit at position 5 in the sequence is directly related to the binary representation for 5. But I've said too much already, perhaps.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OMG  I finally figured it out what your solution is .... awesome.... how did you decide to look at the binary representation and derive the relationship ??

Comment: Just a pattern that I recognised; took a while before the déjà-vu settled in a concrete connection with binary though.

Comment: @aruisdante: How would we do this using generators without extending the list ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are enough hints in the comments that you should be able to find the one-line solution. I think that it's more interesting to try to derive it with a more general tool, namely, implicit data structures. Here's a class for singleton lists.

```
class Singleton:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if not isinstance(i, int): raise TypeError(i)
        elif not (0 <= i < len(self)): raise IndexError(i)
        else: return self.x

    def __len__(self): return 1
```

We can use this class like so.

```
>>> lst = Singleton(42)
>>> lst[0]
42
>>> len(lst)
1
```

Now we define a concatenation class and a mapper class, where the latter takes a function and implicitly applies it to each list element.

```
class Concatenation:
    def __init__(self, lst1, lst2):
        self.lst1 = lst1
        self.lst2 = lst2
        self.cachedlen = len(lst1) + len(lst2)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if not isinstance(i, int): raise TypeError(i)
        elif not (0 <= i < len(self)): raise IndexError(i)
        elif i < len(self.lst1): return self.lst1[i]
        else: return self.lst2[i - len(self.lst1)]

    def __len__(self): return self.cachedlen


class Mapper:
    def __init__(self, f, lst):
        self.f = f
        self.lst = lst

    def __getitem__(self, i): return self.f(self.lst[i])

    def __len__(self): return len(self.lst)
```

Now let's rewrite your code to use these classes.

```
a = Singleton(0)
for i in range(32):
    a = Concatenation(a, Mapper({0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 0}.get, a))
print(a[3000000000 - 1])
```

As an exercise: why do we need `cachedlen`?

Comment: cachedlen is stored so that you can retrieve the len() of the sub-problem in constant time when we get the item using a[N]

Comment: I was able to pull off the 3 billionth calculation using a python list  ( a = [0] ) instead of a singleton list ... Any reason why singleton lists are preferred ??